# Django variable within a variable

Tags: django, variables

I have something like the following

models.py

```
class Proposal(models.Model):
terms = models.ManyToManyField('Term')
```

views.py

```
data = Proposal.objects.get(pk=id) # is sent to template
```

template.html

```
{% for t in  data.terms.all %}
{{ t }}<br />
{% endfor %}
```

My problem is that I am attempting to embed a variable within `{{ t }}`
For instance a term record `{{t}}` might look like:
"This proposal was created on `{{ dateCreated }}`"

How can I get the dateCreated variable properly interpreted?

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to use the dot syntax to access attributes on the related object:

```
{{ t.date_created }}
```

A couple of things to point out: Python attributes are usually snake_case, and doing a `foo.related.all()` in a template may result in more database queries.

Ah, seems I misunderstood your question.